# Nginx Reverse Proxy Problem

Tags: configuration, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am having an issue with my `nginx.conf` file where my proxy_pass for *nas.domain.com* IS forwarded to the correct address, but *cloud.domain.com* is not.

Can anyone please help me figure out what is wrong with my file? My domain name has been changed to protect the innocent:

```
load_module /usr/local/libexec/nginx/ngx_mail_module.so;                                                                            
load_module /usr/local/libexec/nginx/ngx_stream_module.so;                                                                          

#user  nobody;                                                                                                                      
worker_processes  1;                                                                                                                

# This default error log path is compiled-in to make sure configuration parsing                                                     
# errors are logged somewhere, especially during unattended boot when stderr                                                        
# isn't normally logged anywhere. This path will be touched on every nginx                                                          
# start regardless of error log location configured here. See                                                                       
# https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/147 for more info.                                                                            
#                                                                                                                                   
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;                                                                                               
#                                                                                                                                   

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;                                                                                                         

events {                                                                                                                            
     worker_connections  1024;                                                                                                       
}                                                                                                                                   

http {                                                                                                                              
    include       mime.types;                                                                                                       
    default_type  application/octet-stream;                                                                                         

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '                                                      
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '                                                                  
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';                                                                

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;                                                                                             

    sendfile        on;                                                                                                             
    #tcp_nopush     on;                                                                                                             

    #keepalive_timeout  0;                                                                                                          
    keepalive_timeout  65;                                                                                                          

    #gzip  on;                                                                                                                      

    server {                                                                                                                        
        listen       80;                                                                                                            
        server_name  domain.com www.domain.com;                                                                           

        #charset koi8-r;                                                                                                            

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;                                                                                    

        location / {                                                                                                                
            #root   /usr/local/www/nginx;                                                                                           
            #index  index.html index.htm;                                                                                           
            proxy_pass http://192.168.1.5;                                                                                         
        }                                                                                                                           
    }                                                                                                                                   

    #                                                                                                                                   
    #error_page  404              /404.html;                                                                                   
    #                                                                                                                                   
    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html                                                                  
    #                                                                                                                           
    #        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;                                                                                   
    #        location = /50x.html {                                                                                                     
    #            root   /usr/local/www/nginx-dist;                                                                                      
    #        }                                                                                                                          

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80                                                                 
    #                                                                                                                           
    #location ~ \.php$ {                                                                                                        
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;                                                                                         
    #}                                                                                                                          

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000                                                        
    #                                                                                                                           
    #location ~ \.php$ {                                                                                                        
    #    root           html;                                                                                                   
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;                                                                                         
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;                                                                                              
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;                                                          
    #    include        fastcgi_params;                                                                                         
    #}                                                                                                                          

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root                                                                 
    # concurs with nginx's one                                                                                                  
    #                                                                                                                           
    #location ~ /\.ht {                                                                                                         
    #    deny  all;                                                                                                             

    #}                                                                                                                          
    #}                                                                                                                              


    server {                                                                                                                            
        server_name nas.domain.com;                                                                                                  

        location / {                                                                                                                        
            # app1 reverse proxy follow                                                                                                       
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;                                                                                          
            proxy_set_header Host $host;                                                                                                      
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;                                                                      
            proxy_pass http://192.168.1.121:8080;                                                                                             
        }                                                                                                                                   
    }                                                                                                                                   

    server {                                                                                                                            
        listen cloud.domain.com:80;                                                                                                  
        server_name cloud.domain.com;                                                                                                
        location / {                                                                                                                
            # app2 reverse proxy settings follow                                                                                
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;                                                                            
            proxy_set_header Host $host;                                                                                        
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;                                                        
            proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:2080;                                                                                 
        }                                                                                                                           
    }                                                                                                                                   

    # HTTPS server                                                                                                                  
    #                                                                                                                               
    #server {                                                                                                                       
    #    listen       443 ssl;                                                                                                      
    #    server_name  localhost;                                                                                                    

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;                                                                                             
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;                                                                                             

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;                                                                                        
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;                                                                                                   

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;                                                                                             
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;                                                                                             

    #    location / {                                                                                                               
    #        root   html;                                                                                                           
    #        index  index.html index.htm;                                                                                           
    #    }                                                                                                                          
    #}                                                                                                                              

}
```

Comment: Additionally, if someone could help me on how to properly post code so that it doesn't look like this does...

Comment: @Ouki Thank you for reformatting so that my question is readable.

Comment: What happens if you delete the line `listen cloud.domain.com:80;`?

Comment: @richard-smith After making the suggested modification, I receive a 502 Bad Gateway error page.

Comment: The `nginx-error.log` may help, from both before and after the modification.

Comment: Thank you. I found what I had done wrong due in part to your suggestion Richard. I would like to mark your suggestion as the answer. Could you propose an answer?

Comment: I am not sure what the answer is, other than "look at the error logs" :-) Anyway, the main thing is that you solved your problem.